# Grepping through .gz log files

Tags: apache-2.2, gzip, grep, logrotate

Does there exist a magical shell piping which would allow easily to grep through bunch of .gz log files without needing to extract them somewhere?

.gz files are Apache logs, result of log rotation. I'd like to quickly check how often certain URIs are accessed in the past.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The [**zgrep**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zgrep) program is available for Linux (and perhaps some Unix too). This will decompress the files and then grep through them.

Comment: +1. See also: `zcat`, `zegrep`, `zmore`, `zless`...

Answer (score 8):

Should you for some reason lack zgrep you can do the same thing with gunzip and a pipe:

```
gunzip -c <filename.gz> | grep <whatever you want to grep for>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just use `zgrep` to grep through compressed files.

If you need to use a specific grep, you can set the GREP environment variable:

```
export GREP=/bin/egrep
```

Answer (score 3):

How about zgrep?  Seems to be installed on Mac OS and Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 3):

I usually use:

`zcat filename.gz | less`